# Looking for a way to replace a string from a pdf by retaining the formatting

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have two static pdfs. The second pdf is having few place holders.At runtime i will be replacing this place holders with the strings from application property file.Finally i will append the second pdf with the first pdf. The formatting is lost while doing it.Please see the code below,

```
private void appendPdf() throws DocumentException, IOException {
    //Source pdf
    PdfReader reader_Glossary = new PdfReader(GLOOSARY);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader_Glossary, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
    //Adding a new page in the end of the src pdf
    stamper.insertPage(reader_Glossary.getNumberOfPages() + 1, reader_Glossary
            .getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    PdfContentByte srcCbytes = stamper
            .getOverContent(reader_Glossary.getNumberOfPages());
    PdfReader readerOut = new PdfReader(SRC);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(readerOut);
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.processContent(1,
            new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
    String data = new String(strategy.getResultantText().getBytes());
    System.out.println(data);
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(srcCbytes);
    ct.setSimpleColumn(50, 5, 600, 780);
    //replacing the string before stamping
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(data.replace("[Name of covered entity]","XXX"));
    ct.addElement(p);
    ct.go();
    stamper.close();
    reader_Glossary.close();
    readerOut.close();
}
```

I am parsing it to plain text hence losing the information.what is the best way to replace the place holders by retaining the format.Again the string that is going to replace can be of variable length.So after the replace there shouldn't be any overlap/truncation of the text.In the above code i am achieving this with the cost of losing the formatting.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are doing something for which PDF isn't suited. **PDF is NOT a word processing format!** Please abandon your idea because your design is flawed.

Comment: A text extractor is just a text extractor. You can use the underlying framework to determine the bounding box and probably some style information of the text you search. Then you can paint a white rectangle over it and draw your replacement text thereon. But this is awkward. You might instead want to look into form fields which can quite easily be filled and flattened.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : Thanks.This is a business requirement which at the moment they are doing it manually with Acrobat editor and would wanted to automate.I will follow  your advice since the libraries wouldn't help us to achieve this. Instead of editing,i will create the second static pdf dynamically using itext in my java code where i have a better control.

Comment: @mkl : Thanks.I tried the text form fields. I was able to set the text with the text in my application properties.But when the replacement text is bigger then truncated.Also this leaved a grey background on the edited area.Could you please throw some light on how to overcome these.

Comment: *truncate* & *grey background* - this merely is a matter how you style the fields, instead of truncation the font size might be reduced, and backgrounds may be switched off.